# Magento 2: How can create different Tax rate for multiple store for same country

Tags: view, dropdown, rules, price, tax

Is it possible to create multiple stores for the same country (to all states) and each store has assigned for different tax rules?
Example for the **country US** I want to create three different stores.

1) **US-store-1**
2) **US-store-2**
3) **US-store-3**

**And each store has a different tax rule.**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create different stores for US ? it can add lot more complexity to your Magento instance.

Magento allow Tax rules based on postal code, you just need to configure table rates properly to make it work.

You can find some useful information regarding table rates here: 
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html